# How to extract non-UI text from a Unity3d project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to extract all the text from a Unity3D project, including not only UI text but also text in scene, asset, shader and script.

These text will later be used for localization purpose.

Comment: _"but also text in scene, asset, shader and script"_ - so not a small ask then?

Comment: Why not simply asking the used language? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemLanguage.html

Comment: @Everts because you than still need to define somewhere what should be displayed for a specific language ;) no clue though how/why this should be done for shaders...

Comment: @BingXue this question is far to broad. Limit it down to **one specific coding related** issue you have